# AWS APIGateway to Istio ALB to EKS Workloads

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, istio, aws-application-load-balancer

We have a set of microservice APIs hosted on AWS EKS behind the Istio Service Mesh (which is exposed as an ALB ingress).
We have two ALB ingress for Istio, one meant for external traffic (from internet) and one meant for internal traffic (within the VPC).

The APIs are mostly meant for internal traffic. We also want to create an AWS APIGateway route to the internal Istio ALB for these APIs (the APIGateway will manage authentication).

Here are the steps we have completed:

1. We are using HTTP AWS Gateway. We cant use REST AWS Gateway since that only works on NLBs and we have an ALB for our Istio workloads.
2. We have created a VPC connector to allow HTTP AWS Gateway to access our internal ALBs.
3. We can see that the request is reaching the Istio envoy service from the APIGateway but is not getting forwarded further. This is because the API gateway is hitting our ALB but not passing any HOST header. So Istio doesn't know where to send the request.

So, how do we achieve the following:

1. Have multiple internal APIs hosted over a single ALB routed from AWS APIGateway?
2. Ensure Istio forwards the request from APIGateway to the appropriate service?